# How do I display metrics in a custom SonarQube Plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm working on a Java SonarQube plugin, but am still new to the API and making plugins in general.

I've downloaded the Example SonarQube Plugin (from https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples) and have been playing around with it to try get the hang of it.

For a start, I'm trying to simply show the number of Lines of Code of a selected program. In the html.erb part, I have just added some "Hello World" text as seen below:

```
<div> Hello World </div>
```

I already added the metrics option so I think I'm just missing something small.

```
@WidgetProperty(key = "Metric",
type = WidgetPropertyType.METRIC, 
description = "Select a metric (at least one is necessary).",
optional = false )
```

Essentially, I just want to click the Lines of Code metric in the widget options and display its output.

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve the issue is as follows:

Assuming your "Metric" input is as in the question above, the following code in the html.erb file should do the trick in displaying the value of the selected metric.

```
<h3 align="center"><%= widget_properties['Metric'].description -%></h3>
<%= format_measure(widget_properties['Metric'].key, :url => url_for_drilldown(widget_properties['Metric'].key)) -%>
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

Comment: (it's worth noting that the <h3 align="center"> & </h3> part is completely optional)